# Выполнение Python скрипта из другого Python скрипта с визуальной составляющей

Tags: python, linux, bash

Сначала вводные данные:
Есть 6 Python скриптов каждый из них в данный момент запускает по строгой необходимости через терминал, 4 из них не требуют общения с пользователем, просто тихо-мирно выполняют парочку не сложных задач. И есть 2 скрипта которые генерируют условный конфиг файл, но при генерации он задает вопросы и на них надо отвечать. Грубо говоря "Укажите адрес действующего сервера MongoDB" в терминале необходимо ввести эти данные (Банальный MGDB = inpunt() ) и так буквально раз 10 надо вводить что-то с клавиатуры в режиме терминала.
Сейчас встал вопрос о необходимости единого центра управления этими скриптами.

Т.е запускаем start.py и там уже надо сделать запуск этих самых скриптов. Но как запустит из одного скрипта другой в интерактивном режиме? Т.е запускаем условный start.py, а из него MongoDB.py, который уже уже требует ввода данных и режим терминала. Как возможно это реализовать? Заранее благодарю, как минимум за прочтение этого C:

Comment: Сделайте чтобы start.py вызывал скрипт уже с нужными параметрами. тогда второму скрипту и спрашивать нечего не надо.

Comment: @Kers так не получится сделать, точнее, сделать то получится, но будет во много раз затратнее по времени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все зависит от ситуации. например в запускаемом скрипте забили на `__main__` и он выглядит примерно так

script.py

```
a = input("enter")
print("a")
```

то наш start.py будет выглядеть так
start.py

```
import script
```

Когда мы делаем импорт некоторый код будет выполнен. Тот который не спрятан в метод.

А если не забили на `__main__`?

script.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input("enter")
    print("a")
```

То запустить его можно так

```
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code = compile(Path("script.py").read_text(), "script.py", "exec")
    exec(code, {"__name__": "__main__"})
```

Ну и subprocess конечно же

```
import sys
from subprocess import call


if __name__ == '__main__':
    call(f"{sys.executable} script.py", shell=True)
```

Ну и еще можно os.system

```
import sys
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system(f"{sys.executable} script.py")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Последний вариант подошел лучше всего, из за специфики вопроса. И некоторых костыльных решений.

И еще сразу вопрос, а как лучше будет реализовать механизм, чтоб после завершения дочернего скрипта, возвращался обратно в начало родительского? Кроме банального вызова его из конца дочернего скрипта.

Comment: для спасибо кнопка есть. а вопрос не понял я

Comment: @RottenMind если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос